# exclamation mark next to my project

Tags: android, barcode-scanner

I have a exclamation mark next to my project's name, I have read all the topics in Stack over flow about it but I wasn`t able to solve it,
in the Window -> show view -> problems  it shows that "Project 'Barcodereader' is missing required Java project: 'com.example.barcodescanningapp.MainActivity'  Barcodereader       Build path  Build Path Problem" ,does anybody knows how can I fix it?

Comment: add an image that shows your project's configuration. Most likely cause: one or more of your library's aren't compiling correctly.

Comment: @DigCamara  sorry I don`t have enough points to add image :/

Answer (score 0):

Its showing that you have not added the library project in your project. I guess you are using the `BarcodeReader` library in your application, so try to add the library in your project from the `Preference>Android>Add library`.

Comment: there is nothing in `add library` section to add, can you please tell me what should I do now, I`m new in programming

Comment: @GrlsHu sorry unfortunately I dont have enough reputation :/

Comment: But you can upload a screenshot on http://postimage.org/ and provide link. Right ?

Answer (score 0):

if `BarcodeReader` is a library project, import it in eclipse first and then rightclick `yourProject` and then `properties> android`. There you will see add library button at bottom. Your `BarcodeReader` project will appear in the window and you can add it from there.